# In the derivation for Poiseuille’s formula for laminar flow through a cylindrical tube the speed parallel to the central axis increases. Why?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation, viscosity

To start off with, I'm a first year undergrad and do not have much knowledge at all about fluids, and am simply working with context that has been provided to me from a lab script (of a lab I did not do personally- I am doing a peer review assignment). Also, I am fully comfortable with the maths that is being done.

The derivation I am looking at is essentially this: https://chemical-engineering-review.com/en/hagen-poiseuille/

I don't see how the speed parallel to the central(symmetry) axis can depend on the displacement along the axis if the forces are in balance (meaning to me that there is no acceleration).

The position dependence can be seen in Equation 6. There is no dependence only if p(x) is linear, which it isn't(I think).

Answer (score 2):

You're correct, though maybe not for quite the right reason.  Perhaps a better way to look at it is that mass conservation for an incompressible fluid in a steady-state flow, we must have requires that $\nabla \cdot \vec{v} = 0$.  In the case of purely axial flow, this implies that $\partial u_x/\partial x = 0$.  (This is more clearly stated in the [derivation on the Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation))

Another way to look at this is that *if* the flow is purely axial (and the fluid is incompressible and you're in a steady state), *then* the pressure gradient in the pipe must be constant along its length.  You can't have one without the other.

Comment: What about for a gas? In the lab script I have, it is said that the gas will expand as it moves along the tube, and that U_x is proportional to volume, and so, since temperature is constant for a small tube, p' is proportional to 1/p . I am really not sure about what it means for the gas to expand in the tube, as well as why U_x is proportional to the volume because of constant mass flow.

Comment: @Tarnish3d: Ah, OK, I had an incompressible fluid in mind when I did this but I now realize that you didn't explicitly say that.  Will edit to address this point.

Comment: @Tarnish3d For the compressible case you can check my answer to this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/760663/111055 And please ignore the other answer to that question. Bernoulli's equation has nothing to do with Poiseuille flow or with Fanno flow.